# Cannot call value of non-function type '((UInt) -> Data?)!'

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

The following message show up when I convert swift 2 to swift 3
Cannot call value of non-function type `((UInt) -> Data?)!`

```
func parseSJSON(_ data2: AnyObject) {      
    /** INITIALIZE THE SESSION **/
    clearUserInfo()
    if let data = data2.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        let json = JSON(data: data)
        let userID = json["userID"].stringValue
        prefs.setValue(userID, forKey: "userID")
    }
}
```

Comment: `data2` is an `AnyObject`, so it doesn't know what to make of your calling `.data(using:)` on that. What is `data2`, really?

Comment: data2 is a json object

Comment: `data(using: UInt)` is a method of `NSString`, and `data(using: String.Encoding)` is a method of `String`. So, your code has no meaning, if `data2` is not a string. Do you mean _`data2` is a **string representation** of a JSON object_ ? If so, replace `AnyObject` to `String`.

Comment: When you say "JSON" object, are you saying it's the raw `Data`/`NSData` that you received in some network response? Or is it the output of a `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:options:)` or the object you received from Alamofire's `responseJSON`? Show us how you created the object that you pass to `parseSJSON`, and we can tell you how to pass it to SwiftyJSON.

Comment: Data/NSData that I received from http post

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help, I try different approaches none of them work.
And by try and error I change my code to this and it work!

func parseSJSON(_ data2: AnyObject, catalog:String)
    //func parseSJSON(_ data2: Data, catalog:String)

```
{

    clearUserInfo()
   // if let data = data2.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {

   if let data = data2.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
        let json = JSON(data: data)

        let userID = json["userID"].stringValue
        prefs.setValue(userID, forKey: "userID")
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You said

> `data2` is `let object = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments)`

In that case, just pass that directly to `JSON` init method that takes the `NSArray`/`NSDictionary`, i.e. the rendition without `data:` parameter label:

```
let json = JSON(data2)    // note, if parameter is `Any` (the `NSDictionary`/`NSArray` structure of parsed JSON), then do not include `data:`
```

By the way, if you're going to parse it yourself like that, the `.allowFragments` is not needed, e.g.

```
let object = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
```

Or, even easier, don't call `JSONSerialization` at all, and just pass the the `Data` directly:

```
parse(data: data!)
```

And let `parse(data:)` call `JSON(data:)`, which will parse it for you:

```
func parse(data: Data) {
    clearUserInfo()
    let json = JSON(data: data)     // note, if parameter is `Data`, include `data:`
    let userID = json["userID"].stringValue
    prefs.setValue(userID, forKey: "userID")
}
```

---

Previously you said `data2` is a

> `Data`/`NSData` that I received from http post

In that case, just cast it and don't use `.data(using:)`, e.g.

```
func parseSJSON(_ data2: AnyObject) {      
    ...

    if let data = data2 as? Data {
        // use `data` here
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry turn out  data2 is                                                                                    let object = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments)

Comment: See revised answer. Bottom line, either call `JSON(object)` using the `Any` object that `JSONSerialization` returned, or easier, change the method to take a `Data` parameter, don't call `JSONSerialization` at all, and let SwiftyJSON do that for you.